# Menu in Octapolis

Tags: commodore-64, emulation

I have been retrogaming with Octapolis on an emulated Commodore 64. Starting up the game presents a menu offering a choice between one or two players, and between music and sound effects. But I don't know how to use the menu. It does not respond to anything other than the fire button, which starts the game with one player and sound effects. Moving the joystick, pressing the cursor keys, or pressing space doesn't do anything. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: You need to do what we did with pirated games in the 1980s - start at the top left of the keyboard and go along pressing every key to see if anything happens. Also try the joystick in the other port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use F1 and F3 to toggle one/two player game and music/sfx.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Pressing F1 toggles between one or two players, pressing F3 toggles between music or sound effects. Even though I chose music, the flying part still had sound effects. The walking part had music however.